# Angularjs showing a string if the object is null in an html table

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<td ng-repeat="course in student.extracourses">
    <div ng-if="!course">  not selected   </div>
    {{b.note}}
</td>
```

I have a table with some static columns and dynamic columns with respect to  student extracourses. Some students do have extra notes and some do not. How can I show in the table 'not selected' if the 'course' does not exist? I tried this code above and it did not print 'not selected' for those who do not have a course

Comment: I think ng-repeat will only show the student with course and there is no meaning of ng-if inside that.

Comment: Seems like a logic error. If a student does not have a course then it would probably not be included in *their* course collection (`student.extracourses`)

Comment: @Igor if it does not have it, it returns an empty extracourses

Comment: That does not make sense (to me). So if there are 4 courses and the `student` is "enrolled" in 2 of them. Does the array `extracourses` contain 4 items or just 2? If it is 4 what is the value of the 2 "empty" courses in that collection? (undefined, null, empty object, something else....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<div ng-if="course === undefined">` to check whether `course` is set or not:

```
<td ng-repeat="course in student.extracourses">
  <div ng-if="course === undefined">not selected</div>
  {{b.note}}
</td>
```

Or alternatively, check the **[`typeof()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)**:

```
typeof(course) === "undefined"
```

Comment: I think for the `ng-if` you meant to write the inverse, otherwise you get "not selected" for everything that *is* defined. Also the an undefined will evaluate to falsey and an `ng-if` check on a truethy/falsey expression is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, I did mean the inverse. My apologies; fixed!